# django: how to create a column whose default value is now()?

Tags: django, django-models

I am using django model to create a table. And the table has a inserted_time column, and I am using plain sql to insert the data, so in the insert sql I don't want to care about this column since I expected database should auto fill now() to the column (using mysql). But how to create such column whose default value is now() in django model. I am using auto-now, but it doesn't work.

updated:

I created a model as:

```
class TestDaniel(models.Model):

    inserted_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index = True,auto_now_add=True)
```

Then I checked the mysql database after migration, the definition of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `orajob_testdaniel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `inserted_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `orajob_testdaniel_e69592ad` (`inserted_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

From the table definition, inserted_time doesn't have a default value, what I want is to have a default value of now() for column of inserted_time, So what I inserted data using SQL (not django model), it will auto populate that column as now()

Comment: Any... Code? Maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, usage of default values for `DateField` is clearly declared in the Django documentation. [Django DateField Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)

According to the docs, you can do the following:

```
inserted_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This will set current `datetime` to this field. This value will be by default and will be set once you create an object. Warning: now, even if you set custom datetime to this field, it will be ignored!

It will not work if you create your object using plain SQL. Django should use its own ORM in order to set default values.